# indicator like block with hma and rsi

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

I use this indocator "Efmus System : 10 indicators in 1"
Here the link
https://www.tradingview.com/script/Q9xternm-Efmus-System-10-indicators-in-1/

There is not the source code and i want to change somes indicator inside this indicator.

I have try to make the same think just with the EMA but don't works. (i want to use HMA in fact)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can help you with specific problems but can not reverse engineer someone else's script